# Intent from onHandleIntent

Tags: android-broadcast

**I have the code**

```
 public class intentService extends IntentService {

        @Override
            protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        RequestQueue queue = MyVolley.getRequestQueue(this);
                    queue = MyVolley.getRequestQueue(this);
                    GsonRequest<Transport> gsonRequest = new GsonRequest<Transport>(
                            url_transports, Transport.class, null, createMyReqSuccessListenerTransport(),
                            createMyReqErrorListenerTransport());

         Intent updateIntent = new Intent();
                    updateIntent.setAction(ACTION_UPDATE);
                    updateIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                    updateIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_UPDATE, 50);
```

> this.sendBroadcast(updateIntent);

// work

**The Intent is working sending update value**

```
 private Response.Listener<Transport> createMyReqSuccessListenerTransport() {
        return new Response.Listener<Transport>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Transport response) {

                    // send beetwean data
                    Intent updateIntent = new Intent();
                    updateIntent.setAction(ACTION_UPDATE);
                    updateIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                    updateIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_UPDATE, (i * 100) / size);
```

> ```
>                     **sendBroadcast(updateIntent); // dosn`t work**
> ```

```
                }
```

**dosn`t work**

Comment: What I need to pass in createMyReqSuccessListenerTransport() that sendBroadcast(updateIntent) begin worl

Answer (score 0):

I decided the progblemm ny myself

I have to call the intent from handle

```
 handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // send beetwean data
                            Intent updateIntent = new Intent();
                            updateIntent.setAction(ACTION_UPDATE);
                            updateIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                            updateIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_UPDATE, (finalI  * 100) / size );
                            sendBroadcast(updateIntent);
                        }
                    });
```